# How to get method's parameters' package name by javaparser?

Tags: java, javaparser

```
public String do(Person p){}
```

How to get the parameter Person package name?I can only get the paramter type,only get class name.

Comment: You can't have a method called `do`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal clear explanation with sample code

Comment: using javaparser

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

```
p.getClass().getPackage().getName();
```

Comment: using javaparser

Comment: OMG! Javaparser gives you a structure of some type like NameExpr or FieldAccessExpr. The package from getPackage() will of course be com.github.javaparser.ast.expr, but that's not what the OP asked for!

Comment: Question was about JavaParser statement to get package.